# TextInput lost focus after typing one symbol when searching

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a FlatList

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <FlatList data={this.state.restaurants} 
              renderItem={({ item }) => this.renderItem(item.restaurant)}
              keyExtractor={restaurant => restaurant.key}
              ListHeaderComponent={() => this.renderHeaderComponent()} 
              ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}/>
  </View>
```

And have TextInput in header it. I am using TextInput as search bar.

```
 renderHeaderComponent() {
    return(
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', marginTop: 10, borderBottomColor: '#CED0CE', borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'transparent' }}>
        <Icon name='search' size={30} style={{ marginLeft: 10, marginRight: 10 }}/>
        <TextInput
            style={{height: 40, flex: 1}}
            onChangeText={(text) => this.onChangeText(text)}
            placeholder='Type text for search'
            clearButtonMode='while-editing'
            value={this.state.searchText}
      />
      </View>
    );
  };
```

In onChangeMethod i filter my data.

```
 onChangeText(text) {
    const filteredRestaurants = _.filter(this.props.list, (restaurantObject) => {
      const restaurant = restaurantObject.restaurant;
      const result = restaurant.name.trim().toLowerCase().includes(text.trim().toLowerCase());
      return result;
    })
    this.setState({
      searchText: text,
      restaurants: filteredRestaurants
    });
  }
```

**The problem is following. When I type one symbol in TextInput then focus is lost immediately from TextInput? How can I keep focus in TextInput while typing?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use an `auto-bound` method for this, as `ListHeaderComponent` is of type `ReactClass`, and your current method basically re-creates and re-binds its `render` every time the data updates, which is not what you want. This concept is further explained in [this comment](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13602#issuecomment-300608431)

Anyway, for your example, to fix your issues you should

1) Change your `ListHeaderComponent` prop to

`ListHeaderComponent={this.renderListHeader}`

2) Now you want to change your `renderHeaderComponent` method to be an `auto-bound method`, and by doing this a new render will not be instantiated every time you change data ( Or enter text into the `TextInput)

```
renderListHeader = () => (
  <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', marginTop: 10, borderBottomColor: '#CED0CE', borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'transparent' }}>
      <Icon name='search' size={30} style={{ marginLeft: 10, marginRight: 10 }}/>
      <TextInput
          style={{height: 40, flex: 1}}
          onChangeText={(text) => this.onChangeText(text)}
          placeholder='Type text for search'
          clearButtonMode='while-editing'
          value={this.state.searchText}
      />
  </View>
)
```

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, but (only on Android) this solution unfortunately doesn't help...

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this, and to solve it I wrapped the renderListHeader in a React.useMemo hook and passed the state hook as an item to the dependency array.

```
 renderListHeader = useMemo(() => (
  <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', marginTop: 10, borderBottomColor: '#CED0CE', borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'transparent' }}>
      <Icon name='search' size={30} style={{ marginLeft: 10, marginRight: 10 }}/>
      <TextInput
          style={{height: 40, flex: 1}}
          onChangeText={(text) => this.onChangeText(text)}
          placeholder='Type text for search'
          clearButtonMode='while-editing'
          value={this.state.searchText}
      />
  </View>
), [this.onChangeText])
```

Answer (score 3):

This is still an issue for SectionList as of react-native 0.61.5. The `auto-bound` method doesn't work since the ListHeaderComponent re-renders when data is becomes an empty array.

I used the following work-around :

1. Move the text input code at the same level than the section list
2. Using position absolute, position it at the place you want.
3. Wrap it in an `Animated.View`
4. Leverage `Animated.event` to translate Y the `Animated.View`

Code sample

```
const animatedScrollYValue = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
...
<View>
  <Animated.View style={{
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 142,
    left: 30,
    right: 30,
    zIndex: 1,
    transform: [{ translateY: Animated.multiply(animatedScrollYValue, new Animated.Value(-1)) }] }}>
    // Your text input
  </Animated.View>
  <Animated.SectionList
    scrollEventThrottle={1}
    onScroll={Animated.event([{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: animatedScrollYValue } } }], { useNativeDriver: true })}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
    ListHeaderComponent={// Whatever you want but make you include space for the absolute TextInput}
    sections={data}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    renderSectionHeader={renderHeader}
  />
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found another workaround for `SectionList` that seems to work so far, and I'll update this answer if I find it stops working.  Rather than rendering my component in `ListHeaderComponent` I add a dummy section at the start of my data and then use a conditional in `renderSectionHeader` to render it out.

```
<SectionList
  sections={[{ title: 'header', data: [] }, ...sections]}
  renderSectionHeader={({ section }) => 
    section.title === 'header' ? (
      <MyListHeaderComponent />
    ) : (
      <DefaultSectionHeaderComponent />
    )
  }
/>
```

Having worked with some pretty hairy CollectionView screens in Swift/UIKit it's not that different from how we would handle a similar need in that environment so hopefully that means under the hood perf won't be an issue, but again I'll update this answer if that becomes the case.

Another option may be to just add a dummy item to your sections array so that it never becomes empty but I haven't tried that.